# Background color of UIActivityIndicator on UITableViewCell is overridden

Tags: ios, ios6, uiactivityindicatorview

Using iOS 6, Xcode 4.5.

I have a UIActivityIndicator that is on a UITableViewCell (using dynamic prototype cells).  When I call startAnimating, the background color of the activity indicator is changing to transparent.  This occurs whether I create the activity indicator in the storyboard file or if I create the activity indicator programatically.  However, if I place an activity indicator on a "normal" view, the background color is not changed when I call startAnimating.

Does anyone know what causes the change to a transparent background when animating on a TableViewCell?

I can work around it if I set the background color back to what I want, but only after the indicator has actually started animating (i.e. after the screen is redrawn at least once).  However, I'd like to understand the cause if possible, or report it as a bug if there doesn't seem to be a logical explanation of why it occurs.